# Assembly binding error on ASP.NET MVC WebApi application when published to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, unity-container

I've been tasked with maintenance of a ASP.NET MVC 5 WebApi application. Every time I've run this application with IIS Express, it runs OK, but every time I publish it to a IIS site and try to invoke any API method, the following error appears:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or 
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Stacktrace as follows:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]   
System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() +0   
System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() +73
System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.
    CreateDefaultFormatters() +55
System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters(HttpConfiguration config) +34   
System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes) +382
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<CreateConfiguration>b__0() +94   
System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +708
System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +184
Consalud.Seguridad.WebApi.App_Start.UnityWebApiActivator.Start() +93

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an 
invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +260
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +142
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +34   
WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +280   
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +749   
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +49 
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +75

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +850   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +162   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +128   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +170   
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +820

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]   
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523   
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688
```

Library versions:

- Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3
- Unity 4.0.1
- Unity.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.1
- WebActivatorEx 2.0.0
- Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29

Unity is used for dependency injection throughout the application.

Web.config assembly redirection section:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

UnityWebApiActivator class:

```
public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());
            // var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

As far as I could see, the exception is thrown in the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;` line of `UnityWebApiActivator.Start()`.

Comment: Can you translate the exception?

Comment: @Llazar messages are translated now.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine on which it's running (under IIS) to confirm that the actually deployed web.config for that site has those same binding redirects?

Comment: Your version of `Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3` but in stacktrace the version say `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,`. I suppose is a version mismatch and you need to update the packages or install the version that needed.

Comment: @sellotape yes, both `<runtime>`sections are identical. Does it matter that in the IIS published application, Web.config is in the bin/ folder and not in the root folder?

Comment: @Llazar did that already, every project is using the same version of Newtonsoft.Json. Error still happens.

Comment: I suggest you to delete your bin folder and with `-reinstall` command from the package manager update this package.

Comment: @Llazar also did that already, no difference.

Comment: @llazar - that's unusual. Perhaps a publish issue? Are you able to move (not copy) it to the root folder for the site to see whether it makes a difference?

Comment: @Léster Have you ensured that all of your nuget packages are up to date? The issue may be causing because one of your package has dependency on Newton 6.0.

Comment: @sellotape I moved Web.config to the root folder, restarted the app in IIS and now it works as expected. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it fixed it; done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the actual deployed `web.config` file in use on the IIS server (the one in the root folder of the web application) has the same binding redirects in it.

Also of note: any `*.dll.config` files have no effect; they are usually a result of Visual Studio adding them during development and often they are (usually needlessly) deployed by default.

Comment: Thank you. Another detail for those struggling with the same problem: if VS does not publish your Web.config on the root folder, then go to its properties on VS and change its type to "Content". Setting "None" will make VS ignore the file. The setting below that ("Compilation action") only matters if you want to force a file to the /bin folder, not the root.